# How do I join two tables using one common column while maintaining the values on other columns in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

[image]

In Oracle SQL, I just use `FULL OUTER JOIN` for this, but I can't do it in mySQL. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: No need for join, just union the two table with null as missing column as if your column numbers were different

Comment: @Shadow That sounds a bit inefficient. If I have 20+ columns on both tables, do I have to null all those to fit?

Comment: You need to null those columns that you do not want merge with union. Compared to the workaround for full join in mysql, this is efficient, trust me!

Comment: Two more thoughts: by inefficient I guess you meant you may have to spend an extra minute or two on writing the code, not the efficiency of the code, while I was referring to the efficiency of the code. The time it takes to write a code is secondary to how long it takes to execute the said code. Secondly, it is quite unfair to challenge a solution based on a fact or limitation that was not included in the question. Next time please share all relevant facts and limitations in the question as we cannot guess them!